# Need Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ServiceLocation.dll

Tags: enterprise-library

I need the `Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ServiceLocation.dll` as this seems to be missing when I downloaded Microsoft Enterprise Library 5.0 - Hands On Labs. Please let me know the link to download the missing DLL.

Answer (score 1):

I think the DLL you are looking for is `Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation.dll` (no EnterpriseLibrary in the name).  The assembly should be located in the Lib folder where you installed the Hands On Lab.  e.g. `...\Microsoft Enterprise Library 5.0 - Hands On Labs\Lib\`.

Answer (score 0):

I was in the same boat -- it appears that the documentation is incorrect.  The Exception Handling Application Block Hands-On Labs for Enterprise Library, page 3, asks you to add a reference to
`Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ServiceLocation.dll`

and I can only find

`C:\Program Files\Microsoft Enterprise Library 5.0\Bin\Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation.dll`

It's always a pleasure when the INSTRUCTIONS are incorrect, yes?  :)